# Commit transaction within new connection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Given the following code:

```
        var Connection = new MySqlConnection("***");
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("query1", Connection);
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("query2", Connection);
        Connection.Open();
        var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();
        cmd1.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd2.Transaction = transaction;
        var result1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Connection.Close();
        // Connection with MySql lost: Initiate new Connection
        Connection = new MySqlConnection("***");
        Connection.Open();
        cmd2.Connection = Connection;
        var result2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //transaction.Commit();
```

If I try to commit transaction in the last line, I get **"Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction"** error as transaction is still pointing to the old connection.

What's the best option to commit a transaction in this scenario (Connection initialized in the middle of a transaction)?

Should I retry from the beginning?

Comment: When the connection to MySql is lost, the transaction will be rolled back so you must create a new transaction.  Just FYI:  The execution of your code above _may not_ be using the transaction you created.  You must assign the transaction to the `Transaction` property of the command object or pass it in the constructor when creating the command.  I'm not very familiar with MySql so it's possible that it is different, but I would be surprised.

Comment: You are right. I changed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions end as soon as the connection is lost. You can't have a transaction that spans multiple connections. You have to either commit or rollback prior to closing the connection.

You can reuse the same connection for multiple statements, as long as you don't close it. When you open a new connection, you have to start a new transaction too.